# ffmpeg on lubuntu 14.04 armhf

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, ffmpeg, arm

How can I get a modern ffmpeg version on a lubuntu 14.04 armhf device?

I know, that (l)ubuntu 14.04 just supporting livav and i came back on 15.04. But: lubuntu 15.04 isn't working on my armhf device.

There are also a lot of questions out there regarding ffmpeg on lubuntu. But I didn't find a solution for armhf packages.. (just form normal amd64 etc)

does anybody have a good solution?

Cheers